# sfproj - outpath Build error

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, azure-service-fabric, .net-core

Iam trying to build the sfproj using msbuild on my build machine , This is what Iam doing.

```
<target ="package">
<foreach item="File" property="sfproj">
            <in>
                <items refid="servicefabric.files.sfproj" />
            </in>
            <do>
                <exec program="${msbuild14.exe}">
                    <arg value="${sfproj}" />
                    <arg value="/p:Configuration=${config}" />
                    <arg value="/p:Platform=x64" />
                    <arg value="/target:Package" />
                </exec>
            </do>
        </foreach>
</target>
```

The error Iam getting on the build machine is

(_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) -> 
10:25:10      [exec]   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(724,5): error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'App.sfproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Debug'  Platform='x64'.  You may be seeing this message because you are trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this project.

Comment: What project version are you working with (check the ProjectVersion property in the .sfproj file)?  If it's 1.1, have you made sure to restore the project's NuGet packages?

Comment: yes Nuget restore is done before this step.

Comment: It'd be good to have the full build log with diagnostic verbosity turned on ("/verbosity:diagnostic" MSBuild switch).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.1.0` Nuget package contains an MSBuild target that skips building of the sfproj itself (that or makes certain options present in order for it to succeed).

In my case I had accidentally checked in some Nuget package folders into source control that were incomplete. Visual Studio saw the presence of the folder so it didn't try to redownload it. You need to make sure that the `build` folder is present and it contains an MSBuild target file.  Your best bet is just to delete the packages folder entirely to ensure you're starting off with a fresh start.

https://ijustwrite.software/2016/07/20/ouputpath-property-not-set/

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a problem with the same symptoms.  It happened to me after upgrading the Azure SDK, but it seems to me that it could easily happen in a few ways.  The trouble is that there are two paths in the sfproj file that lead into the directory where nuget packages are stored, oddly enough on the first and last line of the file.  This causes problems because you may have overridden where nuget packages are stored (this is not at all uncommon).  Since these are relative paths, it's easy for nuget to get the packages to where you have specified, but for the lines in the project to point to "..\packages" instead, which makes Visual Studio want to restore the packages, but to never think they have been restored as it's looking for them in the wrong place.

To fix it all you need to do is modify the paths in the sfproj file to point to wherever you have your nuget packages set to download (this setting is in the nuget.config file, which can be in any directory above your project directory).

These are the two broken lines in my sfproj file:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')" />
```

Since I have the value ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages in my nuget.config file (which is two directories above my project file), these lines had to be modified to be the following in order to work again  :

```
<Import Project="..\..\ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.props')" />
<Import Project="..\..\ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets" Condition="Exists('..\..\ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.MSBuild.1.3.0\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Fabric.Application.targets')" />
```

And that fixes it right up.  I was lucky: I had two sfproj files, one with this issue, and one without, so all I had to do was diff to see the trouble.